# как пропарсить html текст средствами php

Tags: php, html

Есть определеный html контент (он может быть разным)...
Допустим есть статья:

```
<img src="image.png" width="100" height="80"/>
<p>А вот текс моей статьи...</p>
```

Как видите в начале статьи есть картинка... причем в параметре `src=""` может быть любое название картинки... (не только image.png) 
Мне нужно из каждой подобной статьи средствами php "получить" этот кусок кода:

```
<img src="image.png" width="100" height="80"/>
```

С правильным значением src="" а не тем что в примере..
При этом в статье может быть как одна, так и 10 картинок..НО та которая нужна мне всегда находится в самом начале статьи.. поверх текста..

Comment: [tag:simple-html-dom] тут часто вспоминают по этому поводу, и как более эффективную альтернативу недавно отмечали `DiDOM`

Comment: будет там там у вас, что нить вроде  `$html->find(".content")->find("img",0)->src;`

Answer (score 0):

Если стандартными средствами, то

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$res = @$doc->loadHTMLFile('index.html');  //Здесь может быть и ссылка на удаленный ресурс
if($res)  {
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
   //Тут работаешь с массивом элементов и вытягиваешь что надо
}
```

Или использовать стороннюю библиотеку вроде Simple HTML Dom

Comment: И оно мне покажет все картинки на странице.. а мне нужна только первая..

Comment: И не с index.html а с текста такого как в примере.. с самих тегов

Comment: так возьмите $tags[0] и будет вам первая. а насчёт текста - я показал загрузку из файла, есть еще отличный метод loadHTML, в который передается строка с тегами

Comment: А можно пример..

Comment: @Вадим, вам документации не хватает? http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: Все то же самое, просто вместо loadHTMLFile пишете loadHTML и передаете не путь к файлу, а ваш текст. По поводу первой картинки 
`if($res)  {
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
  $tags[0] //Ваш элемент вида <img src="" .... />, делайте с ним что хотите
}`

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный путь получения кода первого тега `img` из текста, это использование регулярного выражения

```
/<img\s[^>]+>/i
```

и функции [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: не удобней `>` жадностью ограничить?

Comment: @teran, исключение для этого прописано.

Comment: я вижу, что написано, длиннее просто получается

Comment: @teran, но работать должно быстрее.

Comment: вот к поэтому и вопрос. есть ли разница по эффективности

Comment: @teran, нужно много тестов на разнообразных данных :)